# SOQL Query Knowledge Article by Lookup Field Object ID

Tags: soql, api, relationships, knowledge

I have an article type "Lesson" that has a lookup relationship with an object "Chapter". I want to do a SOQL query (via REST API) to get all Lessons that are in a list of Chapters. It looks like this:

```
SELECT Title, UrlName FROM Lesson__kav WHERE Chapter__r.Id IN ( 'a036100000CCS8jAAH', 'a036100000CCS9sAAH')
```

However, I am getting this error:

> MALFORMED_QUERY: Implementation restriction: When querying or searching the Lesson__kav object, you must filter using the following syntax: Id = [single ID], Id IN [list of ID's] or PublishStatus = [status]. In addition PublishStatus is only permitted in a top-level AND condition.

When I try square brackets instead of parentheses:

```
SELECT Title, UrlName FROM Lesson__kav WHERE Chapter__r.Id IN [ 'a036100000CCS8jAAH', 'a036100000CCS9sAAH']
```

I get:

> MALFORMED_QUERY: 
>   Lesson__kav WHERE Chapter__r.Id IN [ 'a036100000CCS8jAAH', 'a036100000CCS9sAAH']
>                                   ^
>   ERROR at Row:1:Column:60
>   Bind variables only allowed in Apex code

I can't quite figure out if I'm having a format issue or if this is something I simply cannot do outside of Apex code.

Answer (score 4):

If you check out the [salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.202.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticleversion.htm) you must:

When ObjectTypeName equals to KnowledgeArticleVersion or any article type API Name in the FROM clause, a WHERE clause must be specified with one of the following parameters:

- PublishStatus to query articles depending on their status in the publishing cycle:

  - WHERE PublishStatus='online' for published articles
  - WHERE PublishStatus='archived' for archived articles
  - WHERE PublishStatus='draft' for draft articles
- Id to query an article based on its id

**Example**

```
SELECT Id, Title
FROM Offer__kav
WHERE PublishStatus='Draft'
AND Language = 'en_US'
WITH DATA CATEGORY Geography__c AT (france__c,usa__c) AND Product__c ABOVE dsl__c
```

Comment: I tried PublishStatus='Online' and got the same Bind variable error:

I decided to just try querying using the format you provided.
Error:
`MALFORMED_QUERY: Implementation restriction: When querying the Lesson__kav object, you must filter using the following syntax: Id = [single ID], Id IN [list of ID's] or Language = [language ISO code]. In addition Language is only permitted in a top-level AND condition.`